# The equivalent of a GUI "Quick Open" in Emacs on CLI?

Tags: emacs

The title probably doesn't describe this question well enough.  Many GUI-based editors allow you to press a key combination and then start typing a file name (anywhere, in any directory) and as you're typing, a list is filtered down of all the files matching that pattern, in realtime.  If you hit enter, the currently highlighted file will be opened, or if you hit the UP or DOWN arrows you can change the selection.  For example, in TextMate and Sublime Text 2 (on OS X) this is achieved by hitting CMD+T.

[image]

Now I know about `find-dired` and `find-grep` in Emacs, but is there anything else available that's a little more instant?  The annoying thing with dired is that you have to hit enter and perform the search in order to see if the filename was correct.  This is ok if you know the filename, but not so good when you're going based on educated guesses.  It seems like something emacs could be suited to.  Set the directory to index (just once) then when searching filter the index using a Radix tree search or some such, using a split window to show files and responding to the UP and DOWN arrows to adjust the selection.

Anything out there? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ido-mode is perfect for this. It has countless useful applications, including fuzzy filename matching as you demonstrated in your picture.

[image: ido-mode running in my emacs]

Some things to get started:

- [What You Can Learn From ido-mode](https://vimeo.com/1013263)
- [EmacsWiki article](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings#toc1)
- [Introduction to Ido Mode](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/introduction-to-ido-mode)

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! Still reading and playing around, but this is definitely what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Anything.el does this with files and it can do much more. [Here's a good introduction](http://metasandwich.com/2010/07/30/what-can-i-get-for-10-dolla-anything-el/) on how to use it.

Comment: There's a fork of Anything by the name of Helm, which is intended to be an update & replacement: https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm

Answer (score 0):

ido-mode is great on its own, but you may find the likes of [Find File In Project](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindFileInProject) a better option for matching filename patterns anywhere within a directory tree.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-file-in-project` <kbd>RET</kbd> chooses the root of the directory tree automatically (based on the directory-local variables file).

I'm just now noticing that the <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ffip-find-file-in-dirtree` <kbd>RET</kbd> which I also have available (and which works on arbitrary specified directory trees, irrespective of project files) is actually provided by the ffip.el included with nxhtml.

The latter also looks like it supports ido when it's enabled. (Actually, there's a bug, but change `(if (memq ido-mode '(file 'both))` to `(if (memq ido-mode (list 'file 'both))` in `(defun ffip-find-file-in-project (file) ...)`

There will doubtless be a variety of similar options available.

Comment: The nxhtml ffip.el can be found here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~nxhtml/nxhtml/main/view/head:/util/ffip.el

Answer (score 0):

[peepopen](https://peepcode.com/products/peepopen) also provides this functionality

Answer (score 0):

I found it where I didn't want to :( ...

A plugin, called "Control-P" for vim - provides the exact same functionality the author of the question is looking for.

For example - on this video - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhqsjUUHj6g - go to 26:55, and there you'll find a quick and very clean example of it. So, with one command you point to the doc-root, and after that - you're good to go :) ...

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, none of these work the same way :D ... 
I've used "Sublime text 2" for a long time TOO ... and yesterday decided to try using "emacs" ("vim" is very uncomfortable). So, I wanted this functionality:

1. You point to the root folder of a project.

And voila - you have "quick-find" functionality.

But ... there is no such functionality :( ...

(for example - "find-file-in-project" - it requires you to set-up "a file" in the root directory of the project, so it will know that it's the root of your project ... but what if I have to work on several projects simultaneously? ... some of them - use git, some of them - SVN, and some of them - none of these ... :D ... "Sublime text" handle this situation on-the-fly ... but emacs and vim - no :( ...)

Still waiting for the answer though ...

Comment: ffip provides *many* different ways of determining the project root automatically (read the library commentary). Depending on the project, some of them require no special configuration at all, but in any case I would suggest that a one-time action per-project to tell Emacs where the project root is for all future actions is better than having to manually point to the project root when you want to do a 'quick find'?

Comment: I strongly disagree, cause I've gone through sooo many cases of working with completely different projects - with/without version control, different languages (PHP, Python, or plain HTML/CSS) - so pointing manually to the document root is the easiest and most efficient way ... for sure! ... (Probably all your projects are of one type only and/or you have to work on one project at a time ... - but in my case it's exactly the opposite.) ... that's why a functionality like the one in "Sublime Text" is perfect for me - point to the doc root - and voila! ... you have quick find for that doc root :)

Comment: I do work on multiple projects -- that's why I like that ffip picks the correct one automatically when I call it -- and if I need a one-off quick find for something which isn't a real project, there's `find-name-dired`. We clearly do have different use cases, though. Hopefully you'll find/write something which meets your needs.